# CSS code not showing up on the Chrome Debugger when i inspect elelment

Tags: html, css

So I have this CSS code that removes default values on the browsers

```
/* Box sizing rules */
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
​
/* Remove default padding */
ul[class],
ol[class] {
    padding: 0;
}
​
/* Remove default margin */
body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
p,
ul[class],
ol[class],
li,
figure,
figcaption,
blockquote,
dl,
dd {
    margin: 0;
}
​
/* Set core body defaults */
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
​
/* Remove list styles on ul, ol elements with a class attribute */
ul[class],
ol[class] {
    list-style: none;
}
```

and so on.
However, when I open the html file on google chrome, the default margin for the body is still displayed when I inspect element. The code that I see for the body is

```
body {
    display: block;
    margin: 8px;
}
```

What should be shown is my block of code that removes default margin, but the default values (user agent stylesheet) are still present in the chrome debugger. I never mention the body selector anywhere else in my css file, so my code should definitely be overriding them. How can I fix this issue? Why are the default values taking precedence and why isn't my code even showing in the chrome debugger? What's weird is that this is happening only for the body. When I hover over h1 or ul[class] or any other element I used, I can see that the default values have been crossed out and my css code is visible there. The only thing that has worked for me so far to get rid of the margin in the body is adding a class or id for the body and setting margin to 0 within that class or id. But that just seems like egregious code. Any solutions?

Comment: Most probably you havea typo somewhere. Try only putting the body style in the css. make sure all paths to all files are correct and get loaded without any 404

Answer (score 0):

Try using the * selector to reset the default properties for the body element. Then specify custom properties using classes as normal. Like so:

```
body * {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> body {
>   display: block;
>   margin: 8px;
> }
> ```

These are the default styles for the `body` tag in chrome. If your CSS `body` selector does not show, Most likely you did not import the CSS file in the head of the HTML eg.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheet.css">
</head>
</html>
```

Or you just made a typo in the directory.